# Custom datepicker html helper for mvc4 using Razor View

Tags: c#-4.0, razor, datepicker

Are there any tutorial for datepicker control for mvc4 using razor view .
I went through the below mentioned link but sadly it uses aspx instead of razor.

http://www.codesprouts.com/post/Creating-A-DatePicker-Extension-In-ASPNet-MVC.aspx

Could any one please help me in creating datepicker control html helper using razor view.

The main problem is being that i have to get the date picker control in IE8 browser and sadly Jquery Datepicker control doesnt seem to be working in IE8 browser, i tried with several versions of Jquery Library as well. Because of this reason i wanted to build my own custom datepicker html helper . Please suggest some solution

Comment: Take a look at this site: http://20fingers2brains.blogspot.com.br/2013/05/jquery-datepicker-inline-mode-in-mvc3.html

Answer (score 0):

Look here:

- http://dotnetfever.com/using-jquery-ui-datepicker-in-mvc-4/

This might be helpful as well:

- [Very basic jquery datepicker in Razor](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/12693855/very-basic-jquery-datepicker-in-razor)
- http://www.dreamincode.net/forums/topic/288405-using-jquery-datepicker-with-mvc3-and-razor/
- http://www.codeproject.com/Articles/344292/ASP-NET-MVC3-Razor-With-jQuery-For-Beginners

Comment: Thank you for the help, but the main problem is being that i have to get the date picker control in IE8 browser and sadly Jquery Datepicker control doesnt seem to be working in IE8 browser, i tried with several versions of Jquery Library as well. Because of this reason i wanted to build my own custom datepicker html helper . Please suggest some solution ..

Comment: Hm. I borrowed [someone elses fiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/rbwh7/2/), can you try it in your IE?

Comment: @ Ozren Tkalčec Krznarić  Sadly the solution is not working in my IE 8 browser . I'm running my IE 8 browser in my VM ware , could that possibly cause any problem ??

Comment: Can you try [this](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/5454489/jquery-datepicker-having-trouble-in-ie8)?

Comment: And also the jsfiddle.net links are not working properly in my IE browser, it shows up javascript error ..

Comment: Hey, but this one is indicative! If IE browser in your virtual machine usually shows JS errors, you may have some restrictions to JS code execution or... I think you should ask a new question regarding that.

Comment: The main link (dotnetfever.com) seems to be broken.